# Unable to inject(autowire) a service when test elasticsearch with testcontainers

Tags: elasticsearch, testing, spring-boot-test, testcontainers

So, I want to test elasticsearch with testcontainers. Test containers work well and start good, but when I want to invoke a method from my service this is null, because is not injected, and I don't why.

```
@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
public class ArticleServiceTestDemo {

    @Autowired
    private ArticleService articleService;

    private static final String ELASTICSEARCH_VERSION = "7.9.2";

    private static final DockerImageName ELASTICSEARCH_IMAGE = DockerImageName
            .parse("docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch")
            .withTag(ELASTICSEARCH_VERSION);

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        try (
                ElasticsearchContainer container = new ElasticsearchContainer(ELASTICSEARCH_IMAGE);
        ) {
            container.start();
            ResponseEntity<Article> article = articleService.persistArticle(new ArticleRequestDto());
            assertTrue(article.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful());
        }
    }
}
```

This is my error:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.ArticleService.persistArticle(com.ArticleRequestDto)" because "this.articleService" is null
```

When I run a simpe SpringBootTest (without elasticsearch connection and testcontainers) the `ArticleService` was injected good. But in test with testcontainers this not injected.

Comment: I found the solution. Must to add `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` above `ArticleServiceTest`

Comment: You don't need the `@Testcontainers` JUnit-Jupiter extension, if you start the container by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Please check ArticleService class is spring bean or not, means ArticleService class was annoted @Service or @Component annotaion or not.
When you apply @Component on a class, then Spring bean container initialize as bean object in Spring Bean Container and Spring Container is trying to inject initialized bean object to annoted @Autowired field. And if you apply @Component on class NullPointerException occurs.

Comment: On my ArticleService I have @Service.  This was injected when I run a simple SpringBootTest, but when run with testcontainers this is not injected.

Answer (score 0):

For example this test runs good. And `ArticleService` was injected.

```
@SpringBootTest
public class DemoTest {

    @Autowired
    private ArticleService articleService;

    @Test
    public void simpleTest() {
        articleService.persistArticle(new ArticleRequestDto());
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the SO community and thnaks for aksing your question. But whenever you need to add more details to question please EDIT your question and update it rather then uploading as answer. You can delete this answer and update same details to above question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if `@ActiveProfiles("dev")` isn't messing up the beans wiring?
Your example that runs okay doesn't have it. For example remove it and verify if the test runs?

On another note, if you're managing the lifecycle of the testcontainers yourself by calling: `container.start();` then you don't need the `@Testcontainers` annotation which is from [JUnit extension for Testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/junit_5/)  that looks at the static/instance fields marked with `@Container` and creates & starts/stops these automatically.

Comment: Hi @Oleg Šelajev, I tried without `@ActiveProfiles("dev")`, and it is also not injected. So, my conclusion is that testcontainers somehow influence injection of services, repositories. I also tried change org.testcontainers version, but it didn't help.

Comment: Can you share a reproducer? Because here's what it literally does - https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/master/modules/junit-jupiter/src/main/java/org/testcontainers/junit/jupiter/TestcontainersExtension.java and you don't even use it because there's no `@Container` annotation in the example.